# Fedora is not booting

Tags: boot-loader, system-failure

I have installed fedora and it worked like a charm.

When I rebooted it within say 15 mins, no problem.

But 1 or 2 hours, it failed to boot. No errors just black screen.

I tried other distributions too and the same problem.

Funny thing is it didn't affact windows.

I have tried every manipulation possible like enabling and disabling secure boot or tpm chip.

I even updated my bios too.

I am using linux since 2013, I never experienced this before.

I am using AMD processor and graphics driver.

Can anyone please help me around.

Comment: Remove `quiet rhgb` and similarly looking options from kernel options in GRUB, boot, make a screenshot, edit your message and post the screenshot here.

Comment: Still unable to boot, how do I take screenshot if system doesn't boot. I changed what u ask but no help.

Comment: You have no smartphone? I meant "take a photo".

Comment: Issue is resolved, I rolled back to old kernel. During research I found this is some type of bug in newest kernel.